# Finding a path that passes through a given vertex

Tags: algorithms, graphs, discrete-mathematics

This is a homework question. Let $G = (V, E)$ be an undirected graph. Let $u, v, w \in V$, find a path from $u$ to $w$ that passes through $v$. I know that I can solve this by running BFS on $u$ and then on $v$. If $v$ is a reachable from $u$, and $w$ is reachable from $v$, then I just output the shortest path from $u$ to $v$ followed by the path from $v$ to $w$. The running time would be $O(|V| + |E|)$. However, since I'm just asked about finding any path, and not necessarily the shortest path. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: No, that's asymptotically as fast as you can get. A faster algorithm would not read all of the input and you should be able to show that's impossible.